# Ubuntu 20.04 fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs'

Tags: 20.04, mount, fsck

When I reset my pc after an update for windows, my ubuntu terminal can no longer look at data within my c and d hard drives of the mnt file.  When I use `ls` it produces.

```
:/mnt$ls
ls: cannot access 'd': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'c': Input/output error
```

I attempted to resolve it with the `fsck` command and the results produced:

```
:/mnt$sudo fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.34
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs'
```

Still googling but if anyone who's dealt with this before could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: fsck on a windows partition... how does that make sense? Your problem is on the Windows end. So your fix will be on the Windows end too. Probably something like check disk is needed. Or it is hibernated.

Comment: This^^^ Remember to disable the Fast Startup feature **in Windows**. Even if previously disabled some feature updates tend to re-enable it. Having it disabled is a MUST when dual-booting. And if you don't want to risk an unbootable Windows **never access its system drive (C:\) from outside Windows**.

Comment: @Rinzwind not so easy to know :)

Comment: @Brian Moore 
can you also please provide some logs? before and after what happens with that problem

Answer (score -1):

#### Try to verify power supply to the disk

it's common that this is caused by too small power output; your PSU maybe is set to power saving (for some reason?) or the electricity outlet maybe weird/weak

why this answer? I had the same problem; and after years **yes years** of excluding stuff etc; I suddenly found out - it was my `power outlet` and hilariously enough it solved itself by setting the cable upside down (note; this might not be your case) But the errors; is very much like the power problem. check cables and such; and power modes. Is BIOS configured as SavePower? if it is; try to change to normal or whatever it was before.

as some pointed out; fast boot/hiber/dual boot can all be problematic; use a LIVE iso(linux) to make an image(not copy file by file) as backup first; if that works;

### Links

[Input/Output error on external hard drive and bad sectors](https://superuser.com/q/1410221)

#### if possible; it would be useful to run

`sudo dmesg`
and
`sudo journalctl`

and post the output (**redacting** any sensitive info)
when you power it on and wait a bit; until the problem either re appears; or when you open a terminal and type `ls` and it comes up;

Comment: I appreciate showing your opinion of why this is a bad answer by downvoting; it's good. **however**, how am I going to improve, if you only downvote? ;) at least explain why. didn't it work? did it work but still was problematic? is it badly formatted? for you it might be obvious but for me it's impossible to know.